How to display a dynamic node picture using neovis 2.1.0
The following code displays all product nodes with fixed images：
labels: {
    product: {                  
        [NeoVis.NEOVIS_ADVANCED_CONFIG]: {
            static: { 
                shape: "image",
                image: "drone.svg"
            }
        }
    }   
},   

I now want to display different images on each product node based on its image property， the code below doesn't work:
labels: {
    product: {               
        [NeoVis.NEOVIS_ADVANCED_CONFIG]: {
            static: { 
                shape: "image",
                image: (props) => props.image
            }
        }
    },     
},        

I tried another encoding, but it didn't work either：
labels: {
    product: {
                 
      shape: 'image',
      image: function(node) {
        return node.properties.image ? node.properties.image  : null;
        }
    }     
},    

would anyone please tell me what should I do? Thanks!

Try:
labels: {
    product: {                  
        [NeoVis.NEOVIS_ADVANCED_CONFIG]: {
            static: { 
                shape: "image"
            },
            function: {
                image: (node) => node.image
            }
        }
    }   
}, 


Uncaught (in promise) Error: Option image must be defined for node type 'image'

Do all nodes have a valid value for property image?

I noticed a more direct issue now，when use Neovis 2.0 it  display product caption="name" on node correctly, but use Neovis 2.1.0  label: "name" the node show nothing
